# OSL 2.93 issues

Tags: shaders, osl, source-code

Trying to edit procedural OSL script bricks and I can't seem to get the thing to render. I've just copied a few scripts and the shaders ins and outs appear but theres nothing coming out in cycles when I call for a render. You will save my life if you can open up what I'm doing wrong here, thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Assume you have enabled OSL in the render tab (CPU only).. 2. Could you share your script?

Comment: @Robin Betts oh hi thanks for this comment  you just opened up my world with two words. CPU only and yeah heres the source of the script im using  https://gist.github.com/nomelif/567bb30e31e43c643021 It has the same problems I had creating this material procedurally from nodes so I am back to square one after editing it by simply adding a Height 2 variable. but I think I might have just as easy of time figuring it out procedurally